# Polyline featureclass as water network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, line, network, create

I use ArcGIS Pro. I have a polyline featureclass of a water network. I want to create polygon layer around these lines to became a coverage layer but I want that to be automated and not manual. Can you help me?

[image]